# Нужны ли запятые и почему?

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли в данном предложении запятые, если да, то почему?

*Иду на последний звонок с сестрой (,) перед просмотром фильма(,) со своими друзьями.*

Answer (score 1):

***Иду на последний звонок с сестрой перед просмотром фильма со своими друзьями.***

Запятые здесь не нужны, их **нельзя обосновать**. Оборот "перед просмотром фильма со своими друзьями" по содержанию является **уточняющим**, его нужно обособлять полностью. Но как — запятой, тире? Любой знак выглядит не лучшим образом, да и прочтение тоже.

Предложение **стилистически некорректное**: неясное содержание, необоснованный порядок слов, непонятная коммуникативность (это ответ, но на какой вопрос?). Его даже переделать нельзя — нерусская это речь, неестественная,  мы так не говорим.

Образец правки содержания, но не предложения: *Иду с сестрой на последний звонок, потом буду смотреть фильм с друзьями.*

Comment: А разве нельзя рассматривать как перечисление дополнений? *Иду на последний звонок, [иду] с сестрой, [иду] перед просмотром фильма со своими друзьями*.

Comment: Если это  телефонный разговор (ответы на вопросы), то да, можно. Все три запятые можно поставить, даже многоточие. Или что это?  Автор никаких пояснений на дает, разговаривать не считает нужным.  Кому предназначена эта информация: если ответ, то на какой вопрос.  Люди принципиально не понимают, что каждое предложение  – это не абстрактная единица, а знаки ставятся и стилистика определяется в зависимости от конкретной ситуации.  В школе людям объясняют только одно: учите правила!  Основной принцип классического школьного образования. Это мне тут на одном сайте педагог лично объяснил

Comment: Вообще-то это совершенно верный подход к образованию. С учётом детской психологии. Для примера: сперва ребёнок должен просто запомнить, что если вышагнет из окна девятого этажа, то насмерть. И уж потом разбираться с точки зрения физики почему. Преодолеть этот уровень по всем фронатм невозможно: слишком велико количество знания. Поэтому каждый преодолевает в том (более или менее узком) направлении, в котором учится дальше.

Comment: (Впрочем, замечу, это никак не препятствует повсеместно используемой в школах методе сократова акушерства.)

Comment: Илона Маска нам с таким подходом не воспитать.  А также "Платонов и быстрых разумом Невтонов"? А что это у вас за сократово акушерство?

Comment: Ну, это известный метод. Кажется, в конце прошлого века было такое направление "Развивающее образование". Я видела учебники Репкина по русскому языку для начальной школы, очень интересные. Вот там дети  сами находили решения (фонему, между прочим, изучали). А если вы еще и педагог, то за все образование в ответе.  Вот вам наш форум нравится? А вы для сравнения зайдите на другие и увидите уровень образования тех, кто там мнит себя  знатоком. (Кстати, таких, как я, там сразу вычисляют и гонят взашей).  Всё такое убогое, мыслишки куцые, знаний никаких.

Comment: Ну а умные люди где-то в других местах водятся, попрятались все. Мало их, наверное. Так чье это воспитание?

Comment: Образование, обучение, воспитание -- разные вещи. Мне кажется, вы в них путаетесь. // Что же касается других форумов -- я знаю, что там творится, поэтому сижу здесь. Это не только русского языка касается, это во всех перечисленных мной выше сферах так.

Comment: Ладно, будем сидеть вместе. Кстати, почему вы на мой комментарий не ответили (Эти люди (,) словно из полицейского участка).

Comment: Потому что не захотел ввязываться в ещё один диспут. Надо всё-таки себя ограничивать количеством диспутов в интернете, иначе на реальную жизнь ничего не останется.

Comment: А чего там размазывать? Краткость – сестра таланта. Мне бы одного предложения хватило. Вот и модераторы вам говорят об этом.

Comment: Краткость -- сестра таланта и тёща мудрости.

Comment: Этого я не понимаю, хотела в Интернете поискать, но нашла только смешные анекдоты.  Это тоже, знак, наверное, ответ как бы. Ладно, не буду вас от жизни отвлекать.

Comment: Я к тому, что кратко можно как раз изложить правило для запоминания. А вот чтобы разъяснить правило, требуется зачастую многабукаф. // Замечу в целом, что у людей есть тенденция воспринимать краткие, изящные, хорошо сказанные сентенции как истинные. Но ведь из хорошей формулировки не проистекает автоматически истинность.

Comment: Нет у истины примет – может, да, а может, нет.